# How convert Realm data to Json on Swift? Realm version 10.11.0

Tags: swift, realm

until version 10.7.6 of Realm I could convert to dictionary and then to json with this code below, but the ListBase class no longer exists.

```
extension Object {
func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
    let properties = self.objectSchema.properties.map { $0.name }
    let dictionary = self.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: properties)
    let mutabledic = NSMutableDictionary()
    mutabledic.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
    for prop in self.objectSchema.properties as [Property] {
        // find lists
        if let nestedObject = self[prop.name] as? Object {
            mutabledic.setValue(nestedObject.toDictionary(), forKey: prop.name)
        } else if let nestedListObject = self[prop.name] as? ListBase { /*Cannot find type 'ListBase' in scope*/
            var objects = [AnyObject]()
            for index in 0..<nestedListObject._rlmArray.count  {
                let object = nestedListObject._rlmArray[index] as! Object
                objects.append(object.toDictionary())
            }
            mutabledic.setObject(objects, forKey: prop.name as NSCopying)
        }
    }
    return mutabledic
}
```

}

```
let parameterDictionary = myRealmData.toDictionary()
guard let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameterDictionary, options: []) else {
  return 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List` now inherits from `RLMSwiftCollectionBase` apparently, so you can check for that instead. Also, this is Swift. Use `[String: Any]` instead of `NSDictionary`.

```
extension Object {
    func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
        let properties = self.objectSchema.properties.map { $0.name }
        var mutabledic = self.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: properties)
        for prop in self.objectSchema.properties as [Property] {
            // find lists
            if let nestedObject = self[prop.name] as? Object {
                mutabledic[prop.name] = nestedObject.toDictionary()
            } else if let nestedListObject = self[prop.name] as? RLMSwiftCollectionBase {
                var objects = [Any]()
                for index in 0..<nestedListObject._rlmCollection.count  {
                    if let object = nestedListObject._rlmCollection[index] as? Object {
                        objects.append(object.toDictionary())
                    } else { // handle things like List<Int>
                        objects.append(nestedListObject._rlmCollection[index])
                    }
                }
                mutabledic[prop.name] = objects
            }
        }
        return mutabledic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just changed ListBase to RLMSwiftCollectionBase and _rlmArray to _rlmCollection and import Realm. it worked

Comment: Code crashes if I have List<Int> in my data. crash line: let object = nestedListObject._rlmCollection[index] as! Object

Comment: @MohitKumar This was written before you could have `List<Int>`s :) It should be easy to handle this case - just do a condition cast instead. `if let object = nestedListObject._rlmCollection[index] as? Object`. And add `nestedListObject._rlmCollection[index]` directly into `objects` if the cast fails. Does that work?

Comment: @MohitKumar `objects` needs to be `var objects = [Any]()` as well I think.

Comment: yes, this is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Eduardo Dos Santos.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830357/eduardo-dos-santos) Just do the following steps. You will be good to go.

1. Change ListBase to RLMSwiftCollectionBase
2. Change _rlmArray to _rlmCollection
3. Import Realm